# Which Star Wars character is this small green chibi?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification

I searched "star wars chibi" for fun, and I came across [these ones](https://orig08.deviantart.net/8f89/f/2009/268/2/1/star_wars_wallpaper_a_to_z_by_masterbarkeep.jpg), but I don't recognize this character:

[image]

Who is that?

Comment: and no, I _don't_ think it's a [weequay](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Weequay)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### K is for "[Klaatu](http://www.starwars.com/databank/klaatu)"

Klaatu was one of the guards on Jabba's skiff:

[image]

And no, he's not a Weequay; he's a [Nikto](http://www.starwars.com/databank/nikto-green)<sup>1</sup> (Kadas'sa'Nikto, technically).

The image linked in the question is a composite of the "Chibi Star Wars Alphabet" series by artist Joe Wight. The name of the character can be found on [Wight's DeviantArt page](http://joewight.deviantart.com/art/K-is-for-Klaatu-50586357).

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to Omegacron for remarking that one of Klaatu's co-workers was named "[Barada](http://www.starwars.com/databank/barada)". No, [seriously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaatu_barada_nikto)

Comment: [Klaatu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaatu_%28The_Day_the_Earth_Stood_Still%29)?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Clearly, since "Klaatu" is a "Nikto", as in  "[Klaatu Barada Nikto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaatu_barada_nikto)".

Comment: @Randal'Thor Subtle, huh?

Comment: Jason, I like your answer, but I can't LOVE it until it mentions the origins of the character and species' name.  :)

Comment: @WadCheber And lo, it is so

Comment: Ok, I love it now.  <3 But I can't upvote it again.  :(

Comment: Joe Wight's Deviant Art page is amazing. Wow. Glad you credited him. He deserves it.

Comment: @JasonBaker - Barada was his friend and fellow guard, but he wasn't a Nikto. Barada was a Klatooinian. Get it?

Comment: @Omegacron http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9qve.gif. But actually thanks; I've added that in